# MassTransit - Register Consumer to multiple endpoints

Tags: messaging, masstransit

In `MassTransit` how can a `Consumer` register to multiple endpoints?

```
public class Message
{
   public object Payload { get; set; }
}
 
public class Consumer1 : IConsumer<Message>
{
   //... handler code
}
 
public class Consumer2 : IConsumer<Message>
{
   //... handler code
}
```

And I'd like to register `Consumer1` to endpoint_1, endpoint_2 and endpoint_3, while `Consumer2` is registered to endpoint_1 and endpoint_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to manually configure those receive endpoints, and the consumer(s) on each of them, following the guidance in [the documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration#receive-endpoints).

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<Consumer1>();
    x.AddConsumer<Consumer2>();
    
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("endpoint_1", e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumer<Consumer1>(context);
            e.ConfigureConsumer<Consumer2>(context);
        });
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("endpoint_2", e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumer<Consumer1>(context);
            e.ConfigureConsumer<Consumer2>(context);
        });
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("endpoint_3", e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumer<Consumer1>(context);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So now what is missing is how to get the send endpoint using string endpoint name. (Is there another alternative to `IBus.GetSendEndpoint`?)

Comment: Separate question, but [covered in the documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/producers) as well.